# Как с помощью одного стрима выполнить 2 условия, первое из которых требует проверки по всему стриму?

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть коллекция чисел, и, если она содержит числа кратные 3, я вывожу на экран только их, а если нет - то числа, кратные пяти. Я могу сделать это так, но есть ли способ сделать это действие внутри одного стрима?

```
if (numbers.stream()
               .filter(el -> el % 3 == 0)
               .count() > 0) {
        numbers = numbers.stream().
                         filter(el -> el % 3 == 0)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        numbers = numbers.stream()
                         .filter(el -> el % 5 == 0)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: можно, но будет выглядеть сложно, вам оно не понравится )

Comment: верю, но все же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может что-то в этом духе (могла попутать функции но смысл остается)

```
Function<List<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> func = list - > {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(el -> el % 3 == 0) ? 
        el - > el % 3 == 0 : el - > el % 5 == 0;
} 
numbers.stream()
    .filter(number - > func.apply(numbers).test(number))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: это решение пройдет по исходной последовательности N раз. То есть сложность алгоритма будет квадратичной

Comment: Ну напиши сам тада)

Comment: хорошо хорошо, снйчас напишу :)

Comment: Лвдно, хорошо, а если предикат вынести вне стрима и потом заюзать?

Comment: а что это даст? Я могу тебе дать идею, как я думаю срасботает, но ты же меня попросила написать - вот качаю idea теперь )

Comment: +1 за смелость выкладывать явно некомпилируемый код ;)

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
numbers = numbers.stream()
                 .filter(numbers.stream()
                 .anyMatch(el -> el % 3 == 0)
                      ? el -> el % 3 == 0 : el -> el % 5 == 0)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: по сути тож самое, что соседний ответ? (спрашиваю, так как не уверен, не сильно в джаве рублю)

Comment: Неплоха неплоха, но так ведь О тоже будет  квадратичная?

Comment: @Elizaveta вроде да, квадрат тоже

Comment: почему квадратичная? anyMatch один раз пройдет по всему а дальше по нужной ветке. Самая как ни есть O(1) как по мне

Comment: Будет апплаится на каждое число, поэтому

Comment: а фильтр один раз запустится? Если один, то просто линейная сложность N тогда (1 - это когда фиксированное колво операций, не зависимо от колва элементов)

Answer (score 0):

Типо так (вариант #2)

```
Function<List<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> func = list - > {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(el -> el % 3 == 0) ? 
        el - > el % 3 == 0 : el - > el % 5 == 0;
} 
Predicate<Integer> predicate = func.apply(numbers);
numbers.stream()
    .filter(predicate::test)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Более корректное решение *внутри одного стрима*: накопить подходящие кратные числа в разных списках, и если список кратных тройке непустой, выводить его, иначе выводить список кратных пятерке:

```java
List<Integer> filtered = numbers.stream()
    .filter(x -> x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x % 3 == 0),
        (map) ->  map.get(true).isEmpty() ? map.get(false) : map.get(true)
    ));

System.out.println(filtered);
```

<s>Другие</s> Предыдущие предложенные решения использовали два прохождения по стриму в худшем случае.

Comment: `Другие предложенные решения используют два прохождения по стриму в худшем случае.` not anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Также решение в один проход. Суть его в групировке значений по делимости на 3 и 5 в сортированную хеш таблицу.

```
numbers.stream().filter(x -> x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 2, 
            () -> new TreeMap<>(), Collectors.toList()))
        .firstEntry()
        .getValue()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

На случай, если в исходных данных нет значений, которые бы делились на 3 или 5, то можно заранее предусмотреть пустой вывод. Код наверняка можно изящней переписать, но как умею )

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(Integer.MAX_VALUE, new ArrayList<>());

numbers.stream().filter(x -> x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 2, 
            () -> map, Collectors.toList()))
        .firstEntry()
        .getValue()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `partitioningBy` попроще будет :), можно было использовать вариант с `TreeMap<Boolean, List<Integer>>`: `... .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x % 5 == 0,TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))`

Comment: @AlexRudenko я TreeMap взял, чтобы не считать, есть ли делимые на 3 или нет, просто сразу раскидать на 2 категории и отдать первую. МНе как то так удобней показалось и меньше ветвлений в коде.

Comment: я к тому, что можно было сортировать и по Boolean

Comment: @AlexRudenko разница будет минимальная, преимуществ перехода на boolean нет особо, но мое решение можно расширить на больше делителей если придется.